# How to search a word in the middle of the sentence using regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following sentence (String).

***There is a Connection reset error in your server-client communication. Please correct the communicating sheet name.xls.***

now in regular expressions in java how do I find "Connection reset" which is not present in the sentence beganing.
(What I am doing here is extracting the name of the file (name.xls) whose occerence is subjected to the occurrence of "Connection reset" )

I have the expression if it occurs in the start.

->    **Connection reset.*?\b([^ .]+\.xls)\b**

how to modify this to find "Connection reset" anywhere in the sentence.

Comment: You could just use the normal `String#contains` method?

Comment: What good is looking for something you already know? Here is the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iP8vJ6/1) and [here with "whole word" mode](https://regex101.com/r/iP8vJ6/2) Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: actually the sentence -> There is a Connection reset error in your server-client communication. Please correct the communicating sheet name.xls.

So i need to extract the name of the excell sheet (name.xls) based in the occurence of Connection reset. My expression works fine if the "Connection reset" is in the beganing of the line. I needed an expression which could find the word (Connection reset) anywhere in the sentence

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

Dont spin your head with Regular expression,

Use the following code to find the word in the sentence,

```
    String sentence = "There is a Connection reset error in your server-client communication. Please correct the communicating sheet name.xls."

    if(sentence.contains("Connection reset"))
        {
           System.out.println("present");
           String filename = sentence.split("\\s+")[sentence.split("\\s+").length-1];
           System.out.println(filename);
        }
    else
        {
         System.out.println("not present");
        }
```

Comment: ok this could work well for me if it could work for sub strings, What I am thinking is 

string sentence = "There is a Connection reset error in your server-client communication. Please correct the communicating sheet."

    if(sentence.contains("Connection reset"))
        {
           ***some logic to give the name of the excel sheet in the string***
             note- the name of the file may not appear in the end.

        }

Comment: That "some logic" could just be a `Pattern.compile("([^ .]+\.xls)").matcher(sentence)` (or something like that), and so you get the file name.

Comment: Hey, please check out the edited code.
I think this is what you required to get the excel sheet name from the string.
@DipayanDey

Comment: @Rubanraj well ur code will work fine if the sheet name is present at the end but not if it is located smwhere in the middle.
that was the primary reason I opted for regular exp.

Comment: But I guess @fxnn mentioned the proper logic in the comment.
will try and get back ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding something, but what's wrong with

`.*Connection reset.*?\b([^ .]+\.xls)\b`

Answer (score 0):

There is an other alternative witch is to use the methode `indexOf` for example :

```
 string sentence = "There is a Connection reset error in your server-client 
                    communication. Please correct the communicating sheet."
 if (sentence.indexOf("Connection reset") != -1){ 
     // it return -1 if there is no occurrence .
     System.out.println("exist");
 } else {
     System.out.println("not exist");
 }
```